# Joomla 3. How to populate the state of JModelBase

Tags: model-view-controller, state, joomla3.0, populate

I am trying to use the new MVC in Joomla 3 when creating components. I use the JModelBase class for my models. I can not find how to populate the state of such a model. There is no populateState method.

Answer (score 0):

JModelBase has a function for that purpose.

```
public function setState(JRegistry $state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }
```

It's located at /libraries/joomla/model/base.php